# Maven version plugin not working properly

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-versions-plugin

I am using Maven Version plugin and
Executing the  below command

> mvn versions:use-latest-versions

It is updating the version of all the dependencies except one dependency where Current version config in pom. Xml is 4.5.2 but latest version available of that dependency is 4.6.1

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a configuration for versions-maven-plugin in your own pom ? Which version of versions-maven-plugin do you use? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: I am using Maven 3.8.2 and version plugin used is 2.8.1 and I don't have the version-maven-plugin defined in the pom

Comment: That can't be because if you have called it like the given post `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` you must have one in your pom file or something in your settings.xml ...

Comment: Even without defining that plugin , it is executing that command and updating the dependencies versions to latest except for one of the dependency

Comment: As I wrote there must be some kind of configuration otherwise it would have failed upfront... please check if there is a configuration for example in a parent pom file etc... the configuration can influence this behaviour....also please add the full output during the update process etc...

Comment: How I can add the maven-version-plugin dependency in settings.xml

Comment: The dependency can not being add to settings.xml only the pluginGroups see https://maven.apache.org/settings.html